# m1 macos can't install hdbcli

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, conda, hana

I have a script that starts with

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text

hana_engine = create_engine(os.getenv('RCF_HANA_URI'), echo=False)
hana_conn = hana_engine.connect()

postgres_engine = create_engine(os.getenv('RCF_POSTGRES_URI'), echo=False)
```

I need to run it on my m1 macbook. I tried using conda to create an environment with all the necessary dependencies

`conda create --name env pandas sqlalchemy  psycopg2`
`conda activate env`

after `python script.py` I was missing sqlalchemy-hana but conda install sqlalchemy-hana and pip install sqlalchemy-hana failed because they couldn't find a package with that name with noarch or arm64 for python 3.9.

I tried other python versions

`conda create --name env pandas sqlalchemy psycopg2 python=3.5`

this failed for arm64 for python 3.5-3.7. 3.8 worked.

`conda create --name env2 pandas sqlalchemy  psycopg2 python=3.8`
`conda activate env2`

now `pip install sqlalchemy-hana` worked. I ran the script again and got

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hdbcli'`

So I tried to install it

```
pip install hdbcli         
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement hdbcli (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for hdbcli
```

And this is where I am stuck. Is there a way to get hdbcli to work on an m1 mac?

Comment: try with pip3 install hdbcli or python3 -m pip install hdbcli

Answer (score 1):

HDBCLI has not yet been released for M1. You can find the official SAP Note as well as a workaround using Apple Rosetta in [this blog](https://blogs.sap.com/2022/04/25/running-hdbcli-on-an-apple-m1-chip/).